# Is SQL Server 2005 faster when table relationships are defined?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I heard that SQL is faster if table relationships are defined.

Is this true?

Or maybe it's slower, I would like to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're talking about foreign keys. This is also known as referential integrity, and is one kind of [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066(SQL.105).aspx). Foreign keys are not the only kinds of constraints--you can have unique and check constraints, as well. Anyway, referential integrity is slightly slower for `insert`s, and not faster at all for `select`s.

The reason is that it has to check `insert`ed values to ensure that they exist in the other table.

If you want to improve the performance of `select` queries, you want to put indices on columns that you'll be joining and filter on. However, indices do come at a cost, as they slow down `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s, because the indices have to update every time the table changes like that.

So, if your table is high volume `insert`/`update`, don't add too many indices. If your table is predominantly `select`, use indices where you can. The [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx) can help you define those indices for some of your most common queries, as well.

Ensure that you use the Query Execution Plan when running your queries (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in SSMS) so that you can see what SQL Server is doing. You want as many `seek`s as possible, as that means that it's able to use an index most efficiently!

Answer (score 3):

SQL is not faster if table relations are defined.

*Indexes* improve performance; *referencial integrity* (table relations) ensures the quality of data according to business requirements.

Comment: +1 and often data integrity (which RI enforces) is a lot more important than sheer speed ! What good is it if I give you a wrong answer really really fast??